# How to add multiple Excel files with different data in the same Python code

Tags: python, excel

I need to create a python code that can generate different excel files with different data, I already was able to create the code to generate one Excel file with the data that I need, however I need other 3 Excel files or maybe excel 3 others sheets with other data, here's the code that I have:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("proyecto.xlsx")


formato_celda = workbook.add_format()
formato_celda.set_text_wrap()
formato_celda.set_align('top')
formato_celda.set_align('centre')
formato_celda.set_border()


worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("tab 1")

worksheet.write('A1', 'Storage data', formato_celda)
worksheet.write('A3', 'Node', formato_celda)
worksheet.write('B3', 'Phases', formato_celda)
worksheet.write('C3', 'SOC ini', formato_celda)
worksheet.write('D3', 'ESSmax', formato_celda)
worksheet.write('E3', 'Rate', formato_celda)

rowIndex = 4

for row in range(1):
    node = random.randint(1, 62)
    phases = 'ABC'
    socini = random.choice(['0.25', '0.75', '0.50'])
    essmax = random.choice(['0,322', '0,644', '0,966'])
    rate = 6.44

    worksheet.write('A' + str(rowIndex), node, formato_celda)
    worksheet.write('B' + str(rowIndex), phases, formato_celda)
    worksheet.write('C' + str(rowIndex), socini, formato_celda)
    worksheet.write('D' + str(rowIndex), essmax, formato_celda)
    worksheet.write('E' + str(rowIndex), rate, formato_celda)

    print(node, phases, socini, essmax, rate)

worksheet.set_column(0,0, width=12)
worksheet.set_column(1,1, width=12)
worksheet.set_column(2,2, width=12)
worksheet.set_column(3,3, width=12)
worksheet.set_column(4,4, width=12)


workbook.close()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
main()

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your description what the differences are between the three files. If you have different columns, you will need three separate functions (or scripts) for each file. If the columns are the same, but the data in rows are different, use the loop to iterate through your data and write it in the files.